# valgrind finds errors passing pointer to function, but no errors when the code is in the same scope

Tags: c++, pointers, valgrind

I am wondering why, in this example code, valgrind finds no errors or lost memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char *str;

   /* Initial memory allocation */
   str = (char *) malloc(8);
   strcpy(str, "example");
   printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, str);

   /* Reallocating memory */
   str = (char *) realloc(str, 14);
   strcat(str, ".com");
   printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, str);

   free(str);

   return(0);
}
```

However, when I replace these lines with a function:

```
int main() {
   ...
   /* Reallocating memory */
   newstr(str);
   ...
}

void newstr(char *str) {
   str = (char *) realloc(str, 14);
   strcat(str, ".com");
}
```

I am getting 19 errors on valgrind, complaining mostly about invalid reads. However, the program executes and outputs everything the same, without an error. Is there something going on when I pass `str` into the function that happens in memory that valgrind is notifying me of? What can I do to fix this? How can I learn more about this behavior and what the implications are?

This is the output of the program in either case:

```
String = example,  Address = 16445456
String = example.com,  Address = 16445456
```

Comment: Which lines do you replace? Please post the whole program. You will have a memory leak in your second program.

Comment: Your code has some low-hanging fruit that the compiler happily points out: https://wandbox.org/permlink/cYyXdaIJrMnIEVqv

Comment: Why the program operates correctly: Undefined Behaviour may well execute with the behavior you expect. This time. Maybe most of the time. But when you least expect it, or when [your boss is running a demo at Comdex...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73wMnU7xbwE)

Comment: By the way, strongly recommend using `std::string`. Make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, parameters passed to C functions are passed by value. Unless you explicitly pass by reference, or instead pass a pointer to your object, Changes made in the called function will not persist when the function returns.

In your case, you may be passing a pointer, but you are trying to  then modify the pointer in the function instead of modifying what the pointer references.

Apart from the solution provided in the other answer where you return the new pointer, you have two options:

**Pointer to Pointer**

```
void newstr(char **str) {
   *str = (char *) realloc(*str, 25);
   strcat(*str, ".com");
}
```

**Reference**

```
void newstr(char *&str) {
   str = (char *) realloc(str, 25);
   strcat(str, ".com");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

valgrind complain to the read correctly, you read from the invalid memory. You read from invalid value of str.
Correct code below.

```
int main() {
   ...
   /* Reallocating memory */
   str = newstr(str);
   ...
}

char * newstr(char *str) {
   str = (char *) realloc(str, 25);
   strcat(str, ".com");
   return str;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Passing by reference allows you to , among other things, change the referred-to value inside the function. You can do this with a pointer

But in

```
void newstr(char *str) {
   str = (char *) realloc(str, 25); <-- changed the pointer
   strcat(str, ".com"); 
}
```

the value altered inside the function IS the pointer. So you must pass the pointer by reference (or return the altered pointer as shown by BayK)

```
void newstr(char *& str) {
   str = (char *) realloc(str, 25);
   strcat(str, ".com");
}
```

Or you can embrace the power of this fully armed and operational C++ programming language and use a `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string str = "example";

    std::cout << "String = " << str << ",  Address = "  << &str << "\n";
    str += ".com";
    std::cout << "String = " << str << ",  Address = "  << &str << "\n";
    return(0);
}
```